# Bracket troubles with tabular

Tags: tables, siunitx

I would like to center the brackets in lines 3, 5 and 7. For some reason they are not centered and the left bracket does not wrap arround then text. I have also tried fitting the table to increase the width, but with no sucess. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,float}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSS} \toprule
    {$\Theta$} & $\Theta_{\textup{MLE}}$ & $\overline{\Theta}$ & $\Theta_{0.5}$ & $\textup{min}$ & $\textup{max}$ \\ \midrule
    $\alpha_{0}$ & 0.007 & 0.045 & 0.044 & 0.025 & 0.897 \\
      & {[} 0.006 $,$ 0.008 {]}  & {(}0.687{)} & 3.442  & 0.299 & 0.343  \\
    $\alpha_{1}$  & 0.078  & 0.116  & 0.115  & 0.073 & 0.181  \\
      & {[} 0.005 $,$ 0.01 {]}  & {(}1.358{)} & 0.993  & 0.086 & 0.08   \\ 
    $\beta$  & 0.901   & 0.850 & 0.851   & 0.786 & 0.897 \\
      & {[} 0.878 $,$ 0.925 {]}  & {(}1.492{)} & 0.483  & 0.042 & 0.063 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The purpose of the S column is to align (center) decimal points, although it will center {text} if no decimals are found.  So if you want to center [0.006,0.008] you need to put the whole thing in braces.

Comment: In this case, the table would actually look better using c columns (changing 0.08 to 0.080).

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Do you want to write up the comment as an answer? Or should the posting be closed as having been solved by comments?

Comment: @Mico - Go ahead and close it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue raised in the posting has been solved by suggestions given in the comments.